# Different notions of formality

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, rational-homotopy-theory, mapping-degree

Quoting from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_homotopy_theory a simply connected complex is called formal if its cohomology algebra is a model (in the sense of Sullivan) for the cochain complex. According to the quoted article, this includes spheres, H-spaces, symmetric spaces, compact Kähler manifolds, and products and connected sums thereof.

Berdnikov-Guth-Manin in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.12347.pdf use another definition of formality. There a compact manifold is called formal if for some p there is a self-map which induces multiplication by $p^k$ on $k$-th homology for each $k$.

How do these notions of formality relate? Are the above examples formal in the sense of Berdnikov-Manin?(Obvious for spheres and their products, but what about Kähler manifolds or symmetric spaces?)

Comment: I am confused by the question. Berdnikov and Manin appear to only use 'formal' in the sense of Sullivan (see §6.6). Where there are comparisons to other criteria, they give references. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I need to type at least 30 characters to leave a close vote for the "other reason"; the reason is that the author didn't read the paper before asking the question.

Comment: sorry, I had linked the wrong reference. I wanted to refer to Berdnikov-Guth-Manin, now it is corrected

Comment: Berdnikov-Guth-Manin comment on p.24: "This [definition of formality] is not the original definition of formality due to Sullivan ... the equivalence of our definition in the case of finite complexes was first stated by [Shiga, Rational homotopy type and self maps, Journal of the Mathematical Society of Japan, 31 (1979), no. 3, 427–434]."